# Combobox в DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagrid

На форме находится DataGridView. Он берёт данные из DataTable, а DataTable берёт данные из базы данных. Один из столбцов таблицы является в базе внешним ключом, а на форме вместо номера внешнего ключа отображается текстовое соответствие. Было бы неплохо сделать выбор значения этого столбца из выпадающего списка, а выборные значения цеплять из связанной таблицы.

Предприняты следующие действия:

1. В дизайнере форм открыл редактор столбцов DataGridView и в качестве типа столбца выбрал DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.
2. Написал код загрузки данных.

   ```
   var column = dgShihtDM.Columns[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
   column.DataSource = coal.CoalMiningCompanies;
   column.ValueMember = coal.CoalMiningCompanies.НаименованиеColumn.ColumnName;
   column.DisplayMember = coal.CoalMiningCompanies.НаименованиеColumn.ColumnName;
   ```

В результате в таблице действительно появляется ComboBox, но он не раскрывается, но отладчик показал, что в коллекции column.Items есть 10 элементов. Что я упустил?

Comment: а остальные поля редактируются? при редактировании комбобокса нужно сначала выделить поле, при следующем щелчке оно открывается на редактирование и становится комбобоксом. у меня впечатление, что либо таблица в режиме только чтения, либо поле, либо нужен еще клик для перехода в режим редактирования поля...

Comment: Да, вы правы! Как я сам не сообразил? Действительно, этот столбец был readonly. Но тогда другой вопрос: можно ли сделать так, чтобы этот столбец был только для чтения в режиме редактирования таблицы, а при добавлении новой записи readonly = false только с помощью конструктора?

Comment: это точно можно сделать в рамках шаблона mvvm. в вашем случае можно попробовать посмотреть на DataGridTemplateColumn, в котором можно настраивать шаблон просмотра и шаблон редактирования. может там удастся что-то придумать. на вскидку больше ничего хорошего в голову не приходит... посмотрите на мввм. здесь много на эту тему и про листбокс тоже.